# Unable to install pyaudio for python 3.6.5

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04, pyaudio

I have Ubuntu 16.04. My system has 2 versions of Python. One is a 2.7.12(existed by default) and one is a 3.6.5 which I installed. For one of my projects I required the pyaudio module of python for which I typed in the command

> sudo apt-get install python-pyaudio python3-pyaudio

It got installed successfully but the problem is that it got installed only on python 2.7.12 and not for python 3.6.5. 
What should I do to get it for 3.6.5 as well?

Answer (score 1):

you must Simply Download the module with pip:

```
pip install pyaudio
```

then run it on python:

```
>>> import pyaudio
>>>
```

Comment: With pip3 I am getting an error saying " 'gcc' failed with exit status 1"

Answer (score 1):

Use pip3 it's

```
pip3 install pyaudio
```

then run it on python:

```
>>> import pyaudio
>>>
```